# Creating dialog templates in memory on 64-bit architectures

Tags: winapi

Dialog templates for `DialogBoxIndirect()` can also be constructed in memory. MSDN actually has very detailed instructions on how to do this ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes)).

However, there is something in Microsoft's sample code that looks problematic from a 64-bit perspective. It's a function called `lpwAlign()` which seems to take a pointer and align it to a DWORD boundary. The function looks like this:

```
LPWORD lpwAlign(LPWORD lpIn)
{
    ULONG ul;

    ul = (ULONG)lpIn;
    ul ++;
    ul >>=1;
    ul <<=1;
    return (LPWORD)ul;
}
```

AFAICS, when compiled on a 64-bit system, this will cast a 64-bit pointer to a 32-bit integer, pad that integer to a multiple of 4 and then return it as a 64-bit pointer. So this looks like something that will crash as soon as pointer values higher than 2^32 are involved. So how should this code be adapted to work with 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, nobody has done this in the past decade.  Use `ULONG_PTR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `ULONG` with [`ULONG_PTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/21eec394-630d-49ed-8b4a-ab74a1614611) to avoid the 32 bit truncation.

**EDIT**: Also note that the sample code posted on MSDN and quoted in the OP is actually wrong because it aligns the pointer on a WORD boundary, not a DWORD boundary. It should look like this instead:

```
LPWORD lpwAlign(LPWORD lpIn)
{
     ULONG_PTR ul;

     ul = (ULONG_PTR)lpIn;
     ul += 3;
     ul >>= 2;
     ul <<= 2;
     return (LPWORD)ul;
}
```

(taken from [here](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d5/d8e/memdlg_8c_source.html))

Comment: Btw, isn't this function completely wrong? Comments on MSDN say that `lpwAlign` will "align DLGITEMTEMPLATE on DWORD boundary" but what it actually does seems to align the pointer on a WORD boundary, i.e. 2 bytes instead of 4 bytes. So what alignment is required here? DWORD or WORD? I'm confused.

Comment: @myself: MSDN indeed has broken sample code. I've now added a correct, 64-bit proof implementation of `lpwAlign` to David's answer... just for the record because I have a feel that constructing dialog templates in memory in C could become the next big thing ;)